# Regex to replace up to 4 digits before a word

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extension, replace, numeric, regex-lookarounds

I am using this extension for chrome (It's called Word Replacer II) and I'm trying to create a Regex find and replace.

Quick backstory, my partner is recovering from an eating disorder and I want to find all mentions of Kilojoules and kJs and replace them with .

I am entirely new to Regex and after a few hours, I'm not much closer to getting a working expression.

I need it to remove up to 4 digits before the letters "kJs". E.g, 400kJs and 1000kJs. I'd like the "400kJs and 1000kJs" to be replaced with "[removed kJs] and [removed kJs]".

The code I have put together so far is;

```
\s+(a{1,4}<=\d)\s+(?=kJ)
```

And help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `\d{1,4}(?=\s*kJs\b)`?

Comment: Or, `\d{1,4}\s*kJs\b`. Your requirements and your example are somewhat contradicting.

Comment: I just infer from the post body that the matches are replaced with empty strings.

Comment: What if there is a decimal value. `200.23Kjs`?

Comment: Sorry, I put <removed kJs> as the string to replace with, but the body formatting got rid of it! I'll edit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following approach:

```
\d{1,4}\s*kJs\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/peWgFo/1)

If you need to keep `kJs`, you may wrap the right part of the pattern with a lookahead, `\d{1,4}(?=\s*kJs\b)`.

If you do not want to touch 5 or more digit numbers, use

```
\b\d{1,4}\s*kJs\b
(?<!\d)\d{1,4}\s*kJs\b
```

That is, add a word boundary, `\b`, or a left-hand digit boundary, `(?<!\d)`.

**Pattern details**

- `\d{1,4}` - one to four digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `kJs` - a string of letters
- `\b` - a word boundary (may not be necessary if there can be no word starting with `kJs`).

Comment: This works perfectly! Exactly what I needed, thanks so much Wiktor!